# polar form and argument of $\lvert$1+i$\rvert$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to find the polar form and argument of $\lvert$1+i$\rvert$

**My try:**
Polar form is:  $re^{i\theta},$ where $r = \sqrt{2}\;$ and $\;\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ because $\arg(\lvert$1+i$\rvert) = \frac{\pi}{4}$

principal arg($\lvert$1+i$\rvert$) = $\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi$

and the polar form is $\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$

**Question:**
is my arg, principal arg, and polar form done correctly?

Comment: |1+i| has only a real part and no imaginary part. Do you mean 1+i?

Comment: true, i see my mistake, 

is it true arg(positive real ) = 0 and arg(negative real ) = -pi, this I am having hard time of understanding. I made a post about this, still confusing.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: This is what I did: I basically arg(|2+|) = arg(√5) it lies on the 1st quadrant in the Re axis, and there is no rotation and the arg is 0 for positive real number. and for the negative Re it lies on second quadrant (0 + pi) and it will be pi.